# Problems with Physics2D.Raycast

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

<s>In a basic tutorial to make a 2D platformer I was given this bit of code:</s>

```
if (Physics2D.Raycast(ray, out hit, Mathf.Infinity, collisionMask))
```

But Unity says you need `Vector2`s instead of `Ray` and `out hit`. Is there a way I could substitute Vectors for the same value and produce the same effect?

Here's the `ray` code if you want it:

```
ray = new Ray2D(new Vector2(x,y), new Vector2(x,dir));
```

The code is compiling now but it won't actually work (it's supposed to emulate gravity so the character will fall till they hit ground) but it just falls through the ground.

[PlayerPhysics.cs](http://pastebin.com/UnqiChZA)
[PlayerController.cs](http://pastebin.com/VsrNGW3E)

In Unity the character has a Box Collider 2D which is correctly setup and the scripts are both attached and the platform has a Box Collider 2D correctly setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ray` has an *origin* and *direction* components (both of which are vectors) so try this:

```
var hit = Physics2D.Raycast(ray.origin, ray.direction, Mathf.Infinity, collisionMask));
```